# Increase in entropy and integer factorization (How much work does one have to do to revert "irreversible" processes?)

Tags: entropy, work, reversibility, arrow-of-time

This is not necessarily a direct physics question, but I am hoping, that by posting it here, someone can give a hint from the physics perspective.

It is known, albeit not proven, that integer factorization is hard. My point of view of this is the following analogy to physics:

One-Way-functions correspond in physics to the "Arrow of time".

It is not (provenly) known if owf exist, but integer factorization is a candidate for this. ($n=pq$ is the prime decomposition of $n$, given $n$, find $p$ or $q$.)

Since in physics the "Arrow of time" increases entropy, this means that owf should also increase entropy.

Here is an example of what I mean:

Randomly choose some "regular" prime, with low bits-Shanon-entropy, $p \ge 2^N$, where $N$ is a very large number and $p$ is the smallest such prime.
Similarly choose another prime $q \ge 2 ^ M$.

(So to be more clear: Randomly choose uniformly some large numbers $N,M$ and then proceed as above).

**Edit**:
The Shannon entropy of a number $k$ in binary digits is defined as 
$$ H = -\log(\frac{a}{l})*\frac{a}{l} - \log(1-\frac{a}{l})*(1-\frac{a}{l})$$
where $l = \text{ floor }(\frac{\log(k)}{\log(2)})$ is the number of binary digits of $k$ and $a$ is the number of $1$-s in the binary expansion of $k$.
So we view the number $k$ as a "random variable".

Let $n=pq$. Then my conjecture is that the binary digits of $n$ will have a very high Shannon-entropy compared to $p$ and $q$ (on average).

(On the other hand $p+q$ will not increase the entropy (on average).)

Here is a concrete example in SAGEMATH:

```
p = next_prime(2^randint(600,700))
q = next_prime(2^randint(600,700))

n = p*q
```

What I mean by "regular" is that $p$ and $q$ will have many zeros but very few ones and viewed as random variables will have a low entropy.

On the other hand compared to the entropy of $p,q$ the number $n$ has a high entropy.

My explanation for this is, that multiplication raises the entropy of the system $p,q$.

Now the physics question. Suppose I have a box with two container each having some particles $N$ and $M$ in size. The entropy of the left and right container are very low. Now I open the box so that the two container (which would correspond to the primes $p$ and $q$) can interact (multiplication $n=pq$). The entropy of this closed system should increase with time, as happens with the entropy of $n$.

My vague question is this: How much work does one in average have to do, to separate the particles back to their containers (integer factorization) so that the entropy of the left and right box, equals the entropies we started with?

This question could perhaps lead to insights why integer factorization is hard.

Thanks for your help.

**Second Edit suggested by comment of @AndrewSteane**:
The relevant physics experiment as suggested by @AndrewSteane is:

1) increase in entropy corresponds to multiplication:

"If a volume $V$ of gas freely expands into a volume $2V$ (e.g. into a vacuum) then the entropy goes up. So if there are gases $A$ and $B$ both freely expanding into each other, so that each one's volume changes from $V$ to $2V$ then the entropy goes up."

2) entropy stays the same (corresponds to addition):
" If volume $V$ of gas $A$ is slowly merged with volume $V$ of gas $B$ without increasing the total volume, then there is no entropy increase; the process can be done in a thermodynamicaly reversible way"

Suppose we define the "volume" of a number $k$ to be $|k|$ = number of bits of $k$. Then if $|p|\approx|q|$ the number $n=pq$ will have $|n|\approx 2|p|$, so the volume doubles. If $m=p+q \approx 2p$ then the volume $|m| \approx \text{ floor} (\frac{\log(2p)}{\log(2)}) = \log(p) \approx |p|$ will roughly stay the same $|m| \approx |p|$. This would explain why addition does not increase entropy but multiplication does.

**Third edit by suggestion of @probably_someone**:

```
N  = 10^4

def entropyOfCounter(c):
    S = 0
    for k in c.keys():
        S += c[k]
    prob = []
    for k in c.keys():
        prob.append(c[k]/S)
    H = -sum([ p*log(p,2) for p in prob]).N()
    return H

def HH(l):
    return entropyOfCounter(Counter(l))

N  = 10^4
HN = []
HmXn = []
HmPn = []
for k in range(N):
    n = randint(1,17^50)
    m = randint(1,17^50)
    Hn = HH(Integer(n).digits(2))
    Hm = HH(Integer(m).digits(2))
    HmXn.append(HH(Integer(n*m).digits(2)))
    HmPn.append(HH(Integer(n+m).digits(2)))
    HN.append(Hn)

X = mean(HN)
Y = mean(HmPn)
Z = mean(HmXn)
n = len(HN)
m = n
SX2 = variance(HN)
SY2 = variance(HmPn)
SZ2 = variance(HmXn)
SXY2 = ((n-1)*SX2 + (m-1)*SY2)/(n+m-2)
SXZ2 = ((n-1)*SX2 + (m-1)*SZ2)/(n+m-2)
TXY = sqrt((m*n)/(n+m)).N()*(X-Y)/sqrt(SXY2).N()
TXZ = sqrt((m*n)/(n+m)).N()*(X-Z)/sqrt(SXZ2).N()
print TXY,TXZ,n+m-2

Output: -1.43265218355297 -32.5323306851490 19998
```

The second case (multiplication) increases entropy significantly. The first case ( addition) does not.

Comment: How are you defining the Shannon entropy of a single number? Usually the Shannon entropy is defined for a probability distribution.

Comment: @probably_someone: I edited the question, to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Ok then, here's a counterexample to your conjecture: $2\times 2=4$, or in binary, $10\times 10=100$. Clearly $100$ has lower entropy than $10$ (which has maximal entropy).

Comment: @probably_someone: How did you choose $p=q=2$? I don't think this is a counterexample: Choose very large numbers $N,M$. Let $p \ge 2^N,q\ge 2^M$ be the smallest primes. Then $p,q$ will have many 0 compared to 1 ( although I can not prove this, since it requires the existence of primes $p$ which are close to $2^N$). But $n=pq$ will increase the entropy (this is just a conjecture, I have no proof for this.). Of course it is easy to find primes $p$ and $q$ such that $n=pq$ has lower entropy, but randomly constructing the primes as I am suggesting, I think it is difficult find counterexamples.

Comment: I think you need to understand the entropy of mixing better. If volume $V$ of gas A is slowly merged with volume $V$ of gas B without increasing the total volume, then there is no entropy increase; the process can be done in a thermodynamicaly reversible way.

Comment: @AndrewSteane: Thanks for your comment. Is there a physical experiment, which would correspond to increase in entropy in a similar fashion as I described vaguely in my question?

Comment: If a volume $V$ of gas freely expands into a volume $2V$ (e.g. into a vacuum) then the entropy goes up. So if there are gases A and B both freely expanding into each other, so that each one's volume changes from $V$ to $2V$ then the entropy goes up. But by comparing this with the case of reversible mixing, one sees that the mixing itself is not the whole story; rather it is about the number position and momentum states that are accessible to the system. For this reason I think the analogy with your integer factorization idea is too vague at the moment.

Comment: @AndrewSteane: Thanks for your comment. This is very interesting. Suppose we define the "volume" of a number $k$ to be $|k|$ = number of bits of $k$. Then if $|p| \approx |q|$ the number $n=pq$ will have $|n| \approx 2 |p|$, so the volume doubles. If $m=p+q$ then the volume will stay the same. This would explain why addition does not increase entropy but multiplication does. What online book / reference would you recommend I should read to gain a better understanding of the physics in this situation?

Comment: @AndrewSteane: I ordered your book on Thermodynamics, from which I hope to get a better understanding of the physics behind the scenes. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: @orgesleka Your conjecture is still false when $N$ is as large as your example. For the case $N=19$, there are 5,747 different prime numbers between $2^{19}$ and $2^{20}$ with an equal number of zeroes and ones. These primes already have maximal entropy, so there are many, many cases where their product no longer has an equal number of zeroes and ones (and therefore has less entropy than either prime factor). For example, just picking the first two from the list, $559231\times 590207=330062050817$ is one such product. For $N=21$, there are 23,902 such primes.

Comment: @probably_someone: Thanks for your comment. I did what you suggested $N=20$ but I still see an increase in entropy. See the third edit to the question.

Comment: @probably_someone: I understand what you are saying. But my point is to randomly "choose" primes with _low entropy_. Then multiplying these will give on average (where average is meant following the construction above, not randomly choosing primes between $2^N$ and $2\cdot2^N$) high entropy (But adding will not increase the entropy that much). If the primes already have maximum entropy then it is clear, that this can not increase.

Comment: @orgesleka Then this likely has nothing to do with primes at all. If you take **any** pair of "low-entropy" numbers and multiply them together, you're likely to get a "higher-entropy" number as a result, because 1) there's nothing about multiplication that preserves the relative proportion of ones and zeros in the binary expansion of a number, and 2) since you picked "low-entropy" numbers, there are a lot more numbers that are higher in "entropy" than the original pair than there are that are lower in "entropy". You're essentially seeing a kind of reversion to the mean.

Comment: @probably_someone: I did some empirical statistical test, which suggests that multiplication increases entropy significantly but addition does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an order of magnitude estimation.

Let $p$ and $q$ be primes of the form that you propose, and write $p = 2^N + p'$, $q = 2^M + q'$. Then $n = 2^{N + M} + p'2^M + q'2^N + p'q'$.

By the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), the size of $p'$ is around $N\ln 2$, $\log_2 N$ binary digits, and that of $q'$ is around $\log_2 M$ binary digits.

Think about how the binary expansion of $n$ looks: it will start with a 1, followed by many 0's, somewhere about the $N$'th position and around the $M$'th position a small nonzero sequence of digits of length $\log_2 N$ and $\log_2 M$, possibly partly overlapping if $N\approx M$, and again for the last $\log_2(N + M)$ binary digits.

There is no reason to assume that $p'$, $q'$ and $p'q'$ have low entropy, so we could expect them to have approximately equal numbers of ones and zeros.

Let $\alpha$ be the fraction of 1's in a number (i.e. the "probability" that a random digit is a 1), and assume that $\alpha \ll 1$. Then the entropy of the binary expansion of the number, if we treat each digit as an independent random event, is

$$H = -\alpha\log\alpha - (1 - \alpha)\log(1 - \alpha) \approx -\alpha(\log(\alpha) - 1).$$

Let's assume that $M\sim N$, just to make the expressions less cumbersome. Then the probability $\alpha\approx \frac{\log_2N}{2N}$ for both. The probability of a 1 for $n = pq$ then is $2\alpha$, and we immediately see by how much the entropy can be expected to go up.

For example, for $N,M \in \{600,\ldots,700\}$, $\alpha\approx0.0072$, so

$$H(p)\approx H(q) \approx 0.062$$

while

$$H(n) \approx 0.109$$

For the sum of the primes, we get (again assuming $M\sim N$) that $p + q\approx 2p$, which has $N+1$ digits, and $p' + q'\approx 2p'$, which has $\log_2(N+1)$ binary digits, so that, since we don't expect $p' + q'$ to have low entropy for any reason, $\alpha$ doesn't really change at all.

**EDIT** Entropy was computed in base $e$, changed to bits (base 2).

As remarked by @probably_someone, convergence is somewhat slow. To get a better approximation, one can take into account that the number always start and end with a 1, and be explicit about the difference between $N$ and $M$ to estimate the number of ones in $n$.

Comment: @probably_someone $p'$ is of the order $N$, not $2^{N-1}$. If $N$ is not large, the number of zeros obviously is not large either.

Comment: @probably_someone Also, neither 559231 nor 590207 is the first prime after a power of 2

Comment: @probably_someone I think I understand your confusion now (I thought the same too when I first read the question): the statement that the entropy of a product tends to be larger than that of the factors is obviously false, but the OP deliberately starts out with low-entropy primes. This is what I assumed too: $p$ and $q$ are the *first* primes after $2^N$ and $2^M$

Comment: Even with that restriction, the statement doesn't really appear to hold. A script that tries pairs of first primes after powers of two for every power of two from $2^{20}$ to $2^{100}$ found that, of 3,240 cases, only 2,218 had the product have a higher entropy than either of the factors. That's a lot closer to half-and-half than I would expect if the estimate in your answer worked.

Comment: @probably_someone That certainly would be... I'll try to do the same as you did later tonight, to see what is going wrong

Comment: Ok, to be fair, running it from $2^{600}$ to $2^{700}$ shows 4,919 out of 5,050 cases in which entropy increases, with an average change of $0.033$ bits of entropy, pretty close to your estimate, though both $H(p)\approx 0.074$ and $H(n)\approx 0.111$ are about $0.03$ bits higher than you predict. So I guess your estimate might just converge slowly.

Comment: @probably_someone Ok, thanks. That makes sense. I made the assumption that $N$ and $M$ were approximately equal, and I also used that $N$ is large in several places: that the prime number theorem gives a good approximation, in ignoring the lower order terms, and ignoring the fact that the first and last digits are always 1 (rather than not counted, the first, and random, for the last). That it is off by 0.03 still seems a lot, I'll see if I can find out why.

Comment: @probably_someone I accidentally expressed the entropy in base $e$ rather than bits. In bits I get the values 0.062 and 0.109 (for $N = 650$). I'll edit to correct. If moreover I correct the estimation of $\alpha$ to take into account the leading 1 and the trailing ones for $p'$, $q'$ and $p'q'$ (to accelerate the convergence), the first one becomes 0.077 and the second becomes 0.120. This is assuming that, though $N\approx M$, they are somewhat apart (by at least $\log_2N$) so that their ones in the middle don't overlap. If we assume a large overlap, this becomes 0.098.

Comment: Nice! Seems things panned out after all.

Comment: thanks for your answer